# render_form() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'

Tags: python, django, web, render

I am getting this error for my code given below. Can someone help me out

class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,generic.CreateView):

```
fields = ('message','group')
model = models.Post

def form_valid(self,form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: you need to share the code where you call render_form likely in your view.py

Comment: ...and the full error traceback.